# How cancel shutdown from a windows service C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, c#-2.0, system-shutdown

I have a windows service started (written in C# .net2.0).

I want to detect when the computer shutdown/reboot and cancel it.
After the cancel I want do some actions and restart windows.

I have tried it, but it not working

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
partial class MyService: ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new SessionEndingEventHandler(OnSessionEnding);
    }

    private void OnSessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        //Do some work...
    }
}
```

Another test:

```
partial class MyService: ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        //Do some work...
        //base.OnShutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to detect the shutdown whith a winform : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28VS.80%29.aspx

but Windows kill other process before i can detect it, so it's not the better solution!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't mess with this.  Windows will treat your process like a hung process (unless you go direct to the Win32 API).

My suggestion would be to take note that you're being shutdown, and perhaps schedule the activities to happen on startup?

**UPDATE:**
I think you're going to get stuck here, because your service won't know **why** Windows is being shutdown.  You'll have an infinite loop:

- Windows shutdown fires.
- Service notices, aborts shutdown, launches app.
- User uses app to continue the shutdown.
- Window shutdown fires.
- Service notices......
- Etc.

Comment: I can not do my activities on startup because I want lunch a winform application from my windows service when the user loggoff/shutdown/restart.
My winform application have a button "Restart Now", and an other "Remind me latter", and do some other work...

Comment: @scrat: Another no-no, windows services aren't built and shouldn't be used for interactivity with a GUI.

Comment: @James he *did* say that his service would launch another application, though.

Comment: @Neil, the question says `after the cancel I want to do some actions`. I don't see where he states it should launch another app? Also the infinite loop can easily be avoided by setting a flag...

Comment: @James It was in the comment above: "I can not do my activities on startup because **I want lunch a winform application from my windows service** when the user loggoff/shutdown/restart." (emphasis mine).  I suppose you could "set a flag" somewhere, but that's ambiguous, and would be some sort of registry setting or a file somewhere.  It just feels to me like hack-hack-hacking away to get something working that wasn't necessarily a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @Neil: fair point, but it is *do-able*. Yeah you should only be considering services if you have a process that a) needs to be running continously and b) needs to be invisible c) requires no user interactivity....(IMO)

Comment: Thanks for your help, my program work as I want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720125/how-cancel-shutdown-from-a-windows-service-c/2728079#2728079

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to write your actions out to a file or the registry e.g.

```
DoSomething = true
DoSomethingElse = false
```

Which you could read in `OnStart` and process.

Answer (score 1):

`AbortSystemShutdown` might work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376630%28VS.85%29.aspx

Though I agree with Neil that it's probably not a good idea to do this.

Edit: Added sample code

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool AbortSystemShutdown(string lpMachineName);


if (!AbortSystemShutdown("localhost"))
{
    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
```

Comment: How can use AbortSystemShutdown Function in C# ?

Comment: Using PInvoke. Here's some information about it http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/AbortSystemShutdown.html

Comment: Its old but does anyone have a complete code sample for this please? I cant find anything for C# with google. And just don't really understand where to use each of your example's lines in my code. I mean i dont understand where to put the DllImport part and where to use the if() statement to intercept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3916429 Take a look here: [Platform Invoke Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). And the answer to this question looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620396/tutorial-needed-on-invoking-unmanaged-dll-from-c-net

Answer (score 1):

You could use the shell command `shutdown -a` to abort the shutdown. I don't know if it's possible to detect a shutdown though...

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I abort the idea of detect and cancel windows shutdown/reboot, 
But now I **want detect only "shutdown -r -t xx"** !

*Please note the operating system where is running the programme is Windows XP.*

I have try it, but I have no ExitCode with WindowsXP:

```
Process process = new Process();

do
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/a";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ExitCode={0}",process.ExitCode));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
while (process.ExitCode != 0) ;
```

Comment: I've amended my answer above with actual sample code that should hopefully work so you don't have to start this process.

Comment: @ho Windows kill other process before i can detect the shutdown, so it's not the better solution.
I decide to detect the timeout windows when "shutdown -r -t xx" stop launch my program at this time.

Comment: The solution for detect the timeout windows after "shutdown -r -t xx" is based on detect the Title of the windows :
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumWindows