# aborting computer shutdown from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, shutdown

Is it possible to abort computer shutdown from windows service?

Comment: Nice!  Let me add another entry in my Big List of Annoying Things Programs Do.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589986/how-to-abort-shutdown-in-windows-xpvista-programatically

Comment: This is not a duplicate to the question you posted. That question talks about desktop application getting a window message about a shutdown which allows for aborting. A service won't get that window message because it doesn't have a window.

Comment: You can probably abort it in a similar way to notepad blocking windows from shutting down, when it always says "Do you wish to save changes?" and then windows has a fit trying to kill it, and if you press cancel, it's aborted!

Comment: Will - I can think of several *legitimate* reasons for a windows service to do this. One would be a "watchdog" service that stops shutdowns from occuring except if they're initiated by itself, a fantastic safety net for production servers.. If someone accidentally clicks "Restart Now" in an installer prompt, having a service inhibit the shutdown would have definite value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can call shutdown /a using Process.Start

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r";
    p.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/a";
    p.Start();

}
```

The above code tells the computer to shutdown and restart, waits 5 seconds, then aborts it.

Comment: `shutdown /a` only works for shutdowns that have a time-out period. If a user clicks Start >> Shut Down, `shutdown /a` won't abort it.

Comment: Will anything abort it? And even if it does, chances are half your processes have ended anyway, it's probably not a good idea to abort it at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
AbortSystemShutdown
```

I've added a sample to my answer at the similar question here
[How cancel shutdown from a windows service C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720125/how-cancel-shutdown-from-a-windows-service-c/2720191#2720191)

Comment: This will not work for the same reason SLC's answer won't work - AbortSystemShutdown will only succeed when called "During the shutdown time-out period" [MSDN quote]. When a user initiates a shut down, there is no time-out period.