# how to cancel shutdown or restart of windows and make it entering something looks like windows updating more?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How cancel shutdown from a windows service C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720125/how-cancel-shutdown-from-a-windows-service-c-sharp)

I have windows service that should transfer file to nas storage, now the problem is that these files are very important and must not be interupted by windows shutdown or restart,

I want to do something looks like windows updating, when a user hit shut down while the service transfering files in queue, windows should wait until all files are transfered then performing shutdown or restart.

like in this image:
http://www.7tutorials.com/files/img/ie9_uninstall/unie93.png

how to do this in c#.net?

Comment: so what happens when the power goes out?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, there's a command line utility shutdown.exe. One of the command line arguments you can use it /abort. You could just call it at a high frequency I suppose. It's also relatively easy to make a full screen window that constantly "steals" focus and is "top level". It can't, however, stop you from accessing the lock screen.

That sounds like a terrible plan, however. That kind of behavior by a program is not really tolerable, unless it's only going to be you using it. I think a better solution might be to transfer the file under a different name, and then rename it when its completed. Don't destroy the original until the operation is confirmed completed. If that's not possible, then I encourage you to investigate other solutions. Good luck!